# Cron job doesn't work Magento2

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, magento-cron

I created a module and want to use it through cron, and in the end I call the `cron: run` command, here are my files, what is wrong here?

```
namespace AutoAddtocart\BundleAddtocart\Cron;

class Addtocartauto
{

    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(

        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {

        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_logger->debug('Cron run successfully');
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Cron xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job instance="AutoAddtocart\BundleAddtocart\Cron\Addtocartauto" method="execute"  name="add_to_cart_by_cron">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Comment: Run `cron:run` from your terminal in your Magento folder and check `cron_schedule` database table, if your `add_to_cart_by_cron`  job_code is coming or not.

Comment: can you check `var/logs` if logs are printing or not the message `Cron run successfully`